# Why HTML 5 Remove Some Elements?

Tags: html

I just wanted to know **why html 5 remove following elements** please give me answer Its also asked to me in Interview....

The following `HTML 4.01` elements are removed from `HTML5`:

```
    <acronym>
    <applet>
    <basefont>
    <big>
    <center>
    <dir>
    <font>
    <frame>
    <frameset>
    <noframes>
    <strike>
    <tt>
```

Comment: “Why” questions are not constructive and tend to spawn opinionated answers. The official explanations, to the extent they exist, can easily be found in HTML5 drafts, and the rest is speculation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following elements are not in HTML 5 because their effect is purely presentational and their function is better handled by CSS:

```
basefont
big
center
font
strike
tt
```

The following elements are not in HTML5 because using them damages usability and accessibility:

```
frame
frameset
noframes
```

The following elements are not included because they have not been used often, created confusion, or their function can be handled by other elements:

`acronym` is not included because it has created a lot of confusion. Web developers are to use abbr for abbreviations.

`applet` has been obsoleted in favor of object.

isindex usage can be replaced by usage of form controls.

`dir` has been obsoleted in favor of ul.

[See Details W3C](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_intro.asp)

Comment: Thnx Brother for helping me....

Comment: Copy-pasting W3C document with no link to the original document is a copyright violation.

Answer (score 3):

You can find the answers (though a bit short) in the [Differences from HTML4](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5-diff/#obsolete-elements) TR. There, you can also click a particular element of choice to see a more detailed explanation and/or replacement.

Answer (score 0):

Anup not only those tags there are lot of other things which are deprecated in html5. Reason is their function is better handled by CSS.

Please look at this list of deprecated tags in html5 http://www.tutorialspoint.com/html5/html5_deprecated_tags.htm

Comment: Tanks bro It will be helpful